# Why was my edit to this answer rejected?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edit

I asked the [following question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/233644/why-didnt-the-palantiri-reveal-the-fellowships-true-plan/234186#234186), to which an answer was posted by Shamshiel. The answer was detailed and mostly fine, but I [suggested](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/165677) some changes, adding chapters to all the Lord of the Rings sources and making general formatting improvements to make the answer more easily readable.

What was the justification for rejecting this edit?

Comment: Don't have time for an answer but personally I felt a lot of the edits were unnecessary including the video/audio change. It was quite a borderline rejection I must admit though.

Answer (score 6):

As one of the "Reject" votes, I can give you my perspective, but bear in mind I speak only for myself.

Basically, if the edit had consisted solely of the attribution edits, I would have accepted it.  My problem was with the start and end where you changed the OP's text.

"Sound" in place of "audio" and "images" in place of "video" seemed to be purely personal preference, and IMO made the point less clear.  ("Images," without qualification, are in my experience always *static* images; "video" is *moving* pictures.  Similarly, "sound" does not denote the information content of "audio"; sound could just be the hiss of static, and "speech" seems an overly specific type of audio information.)  In any event, the OP's meaning is perfectly clear in the original text; the change does not *improve* the clarity.

At the end, changing the structure and emphasis of the closing argument is also (again IMO) taking too much liberty with the OP's words.

I find the review tools are a bit lacking when it comes to reviewing edits; it would be ideal if the "Improve Edit" workflow allowed stepping through the diff and approving changes line-by-line.  Unfortunately in this case, with the tools available it would have been too difficult to start from your changes and try to roll back the stylistic changes.

Comment: Plus the attribution edits were relatively minor

Comment: @Valorum I don't really see how you can call actively searching for and adding at least five book and chapter sources to an answer as "minor" attributions. In that case what would you consider a major attribution edit?

Comment: @Prometheus - I count three book and chapter sources, not five. The others you've just tinkered around with the formatting.

Comment: @Valorum My bad, I overestimated the amount of references I added, probably due to the effort I made in tracking down the references. I ask again though, if hunting down  chapter and books for three generic sources is not a major attribution edit, what is?

Comment: @Prometheus - Adding a few chapter titles is fairly major *for an attribution edit*, but fairly minor in general terms.

Comment: Personally I feel like video is not as correct as saying 'images', because video is a modern term that I associate with VHS and digital sources. Likewise for Audio vs Sound (granted, speech is used instead of sound).

Comment: It's worth noting that the use of "video" and "audio" was cited by someone in comments as their reason for downvoting. Apparently it's important for some people.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage That might be important in some cases, but OP is speaking as themselves, not as a character from LotR or from Tolkien's time.  Would you require someone to use "wireless" instead of "radio" when discussing a story from the 1930s?  I've worked with a lot of people whose native language is not English; their word choices are occasionally slightly idiosyncratic, but I don't like to correct them unless they're actually misusing a word.

Comment: @davidw wireless is another term for radio, but video and images are different, at least in my estimation. A better analogy is if it was a question cars and traffic. Yes they're related but one is more specific.

Comment: @Randal'Thor: If people want to downvote over a trivial difference of opinion, let them. They're not helping the site by doing so, so why should we care what they want?